# how to assign reader of response to a variable from httpbuilder to controller

Tags: grails, groovy, httpbuilder

```
static def lemp(String aKey,String userName,String tType){
        def temp
         try {
           def ret = null
           def http = new HTTPBuilder("http://192.168.1.10:8080/Pay-0.1/main/msgPicTemp")
           http.parser.'text/html' = http.parser.'text/plain'
           http.request(Method.GET, ContentType.TEXT) {
               uri.query = [ appKey:appKey, userName:userName,tempType:tempType]
               headers.'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 Ubuntu/8.10 Firefox/3.0.4'
               response.success = { resp,reader -> println resp.status


            println reader.text
                temp=reader.text//i got error here,how to assign this to one variable and pass it to controller
                 }
               response.failure = { resp -> println "Unexpected error: ${resp.status} : ${resp.statusLine.reasonPhrase}" }
           }

          return temp
       } catch (groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace()
           return null
       } catch (java.net.ConnectException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace()
           return null
       }
   }
```

Here reader gives the code like,

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Pay-0.1/static/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
    <div align="left" style="background-color:#B8B8B8;width:150px">
    </div>
    Welcome
```

how to assign this reader to one variable and return to controller.and i want to display this one page from controller.

Comment: I believe this issue is with your println reader.text.  Reading from the stream closes the stream.  So your next line, to set the variable isn't going to work.  Remove the println reader.text and see if you still have the issue.

Comment: @Gregg you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your `println reader.text`. Reading from the stream closes the stream. So your next line, to set the variable isn't going to work. Remove the `println reader.text` and see if you still have the issue

Comment: or assign it to temp and then print it... gregg is absolutely correct.